# What is the maximum .NET framework version that can reference .NET 3.5 dlls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webforms, .net-3.5

I have a winforms application built on .NET Framework 3.5 and I cannot upgrade it any time soon. I also have a webforms website built on .NET 3.5 that uses the ddl files of the winforms aplication.

I need to upgrade the framework of the site to 4.5+ or at least 4.0.

My question is: What is the maximum .NET framework version that can I use on my website so that it works perfectly with the .NET 3.5 dlls.

Comment: There is no maximum, all current .NETFramework versions are backwards compatible with 3.5

Comment: [.NET Framework version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#backward-compatibility)